NestJS - Check whether language is RTL or LTR using nestjs-i18
I am using i18 with NestJS and the localization package is nestjs-i18n. I need to check whether the language is RTL or LTR. Is there a method in the given package? My use case is sending localized emails (from backend).
I found that i18next.dir(lang) is available in i18next but not in nestjs-i18n.
My current implementation is,
Class EmailService () {
  ...
  ...
  async sendWelcome (receiver: string) {
    const body = this.i18n.t('email.welcome.body', { lang });
    isRtl = this.isRtl(lang);
    const html = this.render(Templates.WELCOME, body, isRtl);
    this.send(receiver, html);
    
  }
  isRtl(lang: string){
    switch (lang) {
      case ('ar'):
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
  }
  ...
  ...


